# Upgrade from Kohana 2 to latest 3.2 version

Tags: php, kohana, upgrade, kohana-3

I have project written in 2009 and based on Kohana 2.3.4, this project is still active and time to time there is requirement to make fix/create whole new feature. Because Kohana 2 is no longer supported and whole application stack is quite deprecated I have investigated (few times :) possibilities how to upgrade from Kohana 2 to 3. I already know there has been quite a lot of changes and it isn't simple upgrade, it's more like rewrite of application.

Does anybody have real experience with upgrading Kohana 2 to 3? I've found 'upgrade' guides in documentation and few vague statements about upgrade in forums. I just wonder what should I expect in case I would decide to upgrade whole application and if there are really important perks and advantages that will help mi in future of the app.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded a music-blog I wrote around the same time as you from 2.3 to 3.x.  I never released the updated version, and ended up ditching in in favor of keeping the 2.3 version.  The problems I ran into were numerous involving mismatching documentation.  Half the time a link to documentation would lead to the 3.0 docs.  The other half it would lead to the 2.x docs, and then sometimes it would say it was linking to the 3.2 (the version at the time) docs, but was really just an unmodified copy of the 3.0 docs.

The situation became frustrating to the point that I finally stopped developing the new version.  I had no need to upgrade, other than wanting to learn the new 3.x stack so I didn't lose anything.  The documentation may be better now, but at the time there were a number of undocumented changes between 3.0 and 3.2 that halted my development.

Comment: I too get frustrated with the kohana project's lack of care regarding providing a migration path or documentation even across minor version changes.  Unfortunately, every day K2 begins to fade further.  Little things like K2 not having a driver for the newer memcached libraries and such start adding up forcing finding a way to migrate (either to the next version they'll abandon shortly, or to another framework).

Answer (score 1):

I also developed a project with Kohana 2.3.4 in 2008-9. And recently, I was wondering as well as yourself, why I would upgrade. My motivations were :

- New developers who would join my project won't have to go into the archives to get the framework 2.3.4 (that's bad publicity)
- The framework (3.2) code is maintained and get often updates
- Community is more able to help with Kohana 3.2
- There are more modules created by the community for Kohana 3.2

Unfortunately, upgrading is very long : it will be a total rewriting of the code (or 90% of it). Syntax changes for everything : routes, models, directory structure, controller..

After I finally upgraded my project (it was a painful road), I can say that modifications and features of 3.2 offer a complete different vision/philosophy (not everyone will approve) that is remarkable and, in my opinion, more interesting to work with.

Then, yes, I'd recommend to upgrade. And, if you need help, you should go onto IRC :)